# Swift Date Formatter - Different Date from String

Tags: ios, swift, string, date, date-format

I have the following string and I want to convert it to Date:

```
"November 8, 2018 12:30 PM"
```

What I am doing is the next:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy h:mm a"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "November 8, 2018 12:30 PM")
```

But I am getting

```
2018-11-08 18:30:00 +0000
```

and I don't know why. Any tip for this?

Comment: use the `dateFormatter.string(from: date)`. Note that you are using the wrong dateFormatt. MMM is for 3 letters month for the full month you need to use MMMM  `"MMMM d, yyyy h:mm a"`

Comment: And don't forget to set your dateFormatter's locale to "en_US_POSIX" before setting the dateFormat

Answer (score -1):

The date formatter implicitly uses your current timezone, meaning it interprets that date as a local time, then coverts it to a date object with no timezone (UTC+0). It looks like your local time is UTC-6? If I run your code I get `2018-11-8 17:30:00 +0000` because I live in UTC-5

If you use the same formatter to convert the date back to a string, you'll get the same string you put in

```
dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

So no information is being lost. If your string needs to be interpreted in a different timezone other than the current one, you need to set the formatter's `timeZone` property before parsing it.

Answer (score -1):

There are tools out there I like to use https://nsdateformatter.com/

The format you are explicitly looking for is `"MMMM d, yyyy h:m a"`

Your code should read something like:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy h:m a"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "November 8, 2018 12:30 PM")
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
```

Comment: BTW This might crash if the device 12-24h settings is set to 24 hours